# Suppressing message 208 on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a query to get a specific results (from where clause) from all databases on a server:

```
  sp_msforeachdb  'select * from [?].dbo.[table] where field=''666'''
```

I have around 10 databases that contains this table I'm searching... but when I use this query it also looks into `tempdb`, `master` and other databases that do not contain this table.

So it will return:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Invalid object name 'master.dbo.table.

I want to supress this message... I tried `set nocount`, `@@error > 0`, `goto`, `ansi_warnings`.

Comment: It is way cooler to use `42` instead of `666` ;-)

Comment: Well, stop using `sp_msforeachdb` - by default it includes system databases and [there is a bug that can make it skip user databases](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25313/1186).

Answer (score 3):

`sp_msforeachdb` can take a prepared statement, wherein you can use `if` clauses and such. The first hit on google found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459536/SQL-Server-Applying-Filter-on-sp_MSforeachDB

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?''  NOT IN (''tempDB'',''model'',''msdb'')
BEGIN
       SELECT name,physical_name,state,size
       FROM ?.sys.database_files
END'
```

Comment: Well, this solves the problem of not looking in certain system databases, but it does not prevent it from looking in databases that do not contain the specific table. Maybe better to say `IN ('db1', 'db2')` <-- the known list of databases that contain the table. Or a different method altogether if the list of databases is not known or dynamic.

Comment: `IF OBJECT_ID('''' + QUOTENAME(''?'') + ''.dbo.YourTableName'' + '''',''U'') IS NOT NULL` might be better per @AaronBertrand's comment.